# Can I set a BorderPane element's width in FXML?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, borderpane

It seems like I can't set any properties on the `<left>` StackPane. I'd like to set it's width to 200, for example.

```
<BorderPane fx:id="borderPane" fx:controller="main.Controller"
            xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="800.0">

    <left prefWidth="200"> // This doesn't work
        <ListView fx:id="listView"/>
    </left>
    <right>
        <ImageView fx:id="staticImage"/>
    </right>

</BorderPane>
```

I know that I can do this programatically:

```
StackPane left = new StackPane();
left.setPrefWidth(200);
borderPane.setLeft(left);
```

But for purposes of my project I simply cannot do this that way. Are there alternatives?

Comment: I dont think that you can apply `prefWidth` on the `<left>` tag. you should probably create a `StackPane` inside of your `<left>` tag and apply prefWidth on that said StackPane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just translate the Java code you posted directly to FXML:

```xml
<BorderPane fx:id="borderPane" fx:controller="main.Controller"
            xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="800.0">

    <left>
        <StackPane prefWidth="200" />
    </left>
    <right>
        <ImageView fx:id="staticImage"/>
    </right>

</BorderPane>
```

Comment: Yeah that works a lot better! The left pane now has the fixed width I wanted.